# Shadows appear when shrink wrap is used

Tags: mesh, materials, shaders, shadows, shrinkwrap

I want to put decals on the surface of a face object, but I am having trouble with shadows appearing.
I can already remedy this by unchecking the shadows in the visibility, but is there any way to fix this using a material node?

[image]

[image]